# How to make an external goto not break a for loop in batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, random

So I have a script that I'm writing as a pet project that seemed simpler than it turns out to be...I have a for loop that is meant to increment a certain amount of times based on user input but in the for loop, I have a destination statement for a goto earlier in the script. The issue is that when that goto is used it breaks the for and causes the for loop to only provide 1 answer.

Here is the code:

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %player%) do (
:defense
call :defenders
:defense_return
call :colorEcho 0e %operator%
echo.
)
```

The :defense_return is the culprit but it's neccesary because I'm using %RANDOM% so I need it to reference back to when the %RANDOM% is used or else I just get the same output when I really want 2 different outputs.

here is the defenders block:

```
:defenders
set /a operator=%random%%%18+1
REM 707th SMB
if %operator%== 1 set operator=Vigil
REM G.R.O.M
if %operator%== 2 set operator=Ela
REM S.D.U
if %operator%== 3 set operator=Lesion
REM G.E.O
if %operator%== 4 set operator=Mira
REM S.A.T
if %operator%== 5 set operator=Echo
REM BOPE
if %operator%== 6 set operator=Caviera
REM Navy Seal
if %operator%== 7 set operator=Valkyrie
REM JTF2
if %operator%== 8 set operator=Frost
REM S.A.S
if %operator%== 9 set operator=Mute
if %operator%== 10 set operator=Smoke
REM SWAT
if %operator%== 11 set operator=Castle
if %operator%== 12 set operator=Pulse
REM GIGN
if %operator%== 13 set operator=Doc
if %operator%== 14 set operator=Rook
REM GSG9
if %operator%== 15 set operator=Jager
if %operator%== 16 set operator=Bandit
REM Spetsnaz
if %operator%== 17 set operator=Tachanka
if %operator%== 18 set operator=Kapkan
goto :defense_return
```

I really want to make this script work out, but this for loop is causing me issues...Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It's Jäger, not Jager

Comment: Change `goto :defense_return` to `goto :eof`.  You also need to use Delayed Expansion.  So this line: `call :colorEcho 0e %operator%` changes to `call :colorEcho 0e !operator!`.  Then you need to enable delayed expansion with a `SETLOCAL` command.

Comment: it caused errors when using the accented "a", same with Capitao. I couldn't find a way to get the batch file to parse it correctly as well because it would always output "Jäger" as "JΣger".

Comment: I tried that Suqashman and it still broke the for loop.

Comment: There are two accepted ways to end a CALL to a label.  You either use `GOTO :EOF` or `EXIT`.    You CANNOT use a GOTO to get back into your FOR command.

Comment: do you have any suggestions on how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do if I can't do it this way?

Comment: The code snippet you have chosen to share with us works just fine if you make the two changes I suggested in my first comment.  You need to end the call correctly and you need to use delayed expansion.

Comment: I did not see the change you suggested at `%operator%` I changed that and it is working fine! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a misconception here, as already explained in the comments...

The `:defenders` block is a *subprogram*, that is, a code segment that you want to *call* (or *invoke*, or *execute*, or whichever) and when such a code segment ends you want *not* to "reference back" (goto) another place, but to *return* to the point where such a subprogram was called. The way to return to the command that follows the `call` command is `exit /B`, although `goto :EOF` also works for this purpose, but it is more confusing (in most programming languages, the *statement* to do this is called `return`).

Also, when you want to use the value of a variabe that change *inside* a `for` loop, you must use the `!variable!` construct instead of `%variable%` one (and insert `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command at beginning of the program).

Finally, your code may be improved if you use an [array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990/778560). This is the final version of your code after including all previously described modifications:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize "operator" array
set i=0
for %%a in (Vigil Ela Lesion Mira Echo Caviera Valkyrie Frost Mute
            Smoke Castle Pulse Doc Rook Jager Bandit Tachanka Kapkan) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set operator[!i!]=%%a
)

rem Get a Back-Space (ASCII 8) character (for :colorEcho routine)
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%a"

set player=4

for /l %%x in (1, 1, %player%) do (
call :defenders
call :colorEcho 0e !operator!
echo/
)
pause
goto :EOF

:defenders
set /a operator=%random%%%18+1
set operator=!operator[%operator%]!
exit /B

:colorEcho color text
set /P "=%BS% " > "%~2" <nul
findstr /A:%1 "^" "%~2" nul
del "%~2"
exit /B
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. To be honest, I had no clue I could use arrays in conjunction with random variables and never thought to try. This not only fixes my issue but simplifies and compacts my code, thank you so much!

Comment: May I ask you to upvote both this answer and the array's one? Thanks

Comment: I upvoted you Antonio.  This is a great answer.  I should just delete my answer as you have simplified and improved upon the code.

Comment: Sadly I currently cannot upvote but I will when I can.

Answer (score 1):

As I explained above you need to exit the CALL correctly and use Delayed Expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do     rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)

for /l %%x in (1,1,2) do (
call :defenders
call :colorEcho 0E !operator!
echo.
)
pause
GOTO :EOF

:defenders
set /a operator=%random%%%18+1
REM 707th SMB
if %operator%== 1 set operator=Vigil
REM G.R.O.M
if %operator%== 2 set operator=Ela
REM S.D.U
if %operator%== 3 set operator=Lesion
REM G.E.O
if %operator%== 4 set operator=Mira
REM S.A.T
if %operator%== 5 set operator=Echo
REM BOPE
if %operator%== 6 set operator=Caviera
REM Navy Seal
if %operator%== 7 set operator=Valkyrie
REM JTF2
if %operator%== 8 set operator=Frost
REM S.A.S
if %operator%== 9 set operator=Mute
if %operator%== 10 set operator=Smoke
REM SWAT
if %operator%== 11 set operator=Castle
if %operator%== 12 set operator=Pulse
REM GIGN
if %operator%== 13 set operator=Doc
if %operator%== 14 set operator=Rook
REM GSG9
if %operator%== 15 set operator=Jager
if %operator%== 16 set operator=Bandit
REM Spetsnaz
if %operator%== 17 set operator=Tachanka
if %operator%== 18 set operator=Kapkan
goto :eof

:colorEcho
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
goto :eof
```