# Why does my batch file echo the array name and number instead of the string?

Tags: arrays, batch-file, random

I have this code here simply trying to create a file that the name is chosen from a randomized array. Why does it output incorrectly?

Code:

```
@echo off

set i=0
for %%a in (Cow Dog Bird Fish Meerkat Cat) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set operator[!i!]=%%a
)
set /a operator=%random%%%4+1
set operator=!operator[%operator%]!

copy /y NUL %operator%>NUL
```

The file created is titled something like `!operator[3]!` instead of one of the strings in the array. Why is this the case? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: add [`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to the top.

Comment: @Excallypurr, you are your own worst enemy.  You need to use the code examples you have been given as they were provided and heed the extra advice people are giving you.

Comment: I only have a basic understanding of what `setlocal enableddelayedexpansion` does. Therefor I do not know when or how it should be used, that's why I asked this question. With Alex K's answer and dbenham's I have a better understanding of that although still limited. I have incorporated the `%%i` suggestion as well in my code. I am trying to learn as much as I can.

Comment: @Excallypurr, delayed expansion was explained to you a few times in your previous questions.

Comment: Generally speaking, always use it.

Comment: @Excallypurr, in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49355707/why-wont-my-for-loop-using-random-work-in-batch) you said: _"For some reason that I don't know, this code does not output correctly"_, and I replied: _"The 'some reason' because your code does not work is the modifications you introduced in such a code"_...

Comment: Will there ever be a case where using it will cause issues @SomethingDark?

Comment: If you're trying to run the script on something earlier than XP, delayed expansion won't exist, but that's really the only reason to ever not use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex K identified your primary problem in his comment - you are missing `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`.

But you have another problem - your array contains 6 values, but you are randomly selecting an index between 1 and 4 instead of between 1 and 6.

You should use `set /a operator=%random%%%i+1`. Note that true environment variables do not need to be expanded when used with SET /A.

Comment: Yes. Compo pointed that out to the user in their previous question.