# Use a variable within variable substrings in batch

Tags: batch-file

So I want to extract 2 and 3 from the `test` string by a variable that is set separately, `number`. But when I try to do this it outputs: `2` where it should output `23`. Any advice helps, thank you!

```
SET test=123
SET number=2

SET two=%test:~1,%number%%

ECHO two
```

Comment: Read the explanations at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990). Although the topic is different, the solution is the same...

Comment: You essentially asked this same type of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410637/why-does-my-batch-file-echo-the-array-name-and-number-instead-of-the-string) before.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue you must use `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` and `!` instead of `%` for the `SET` statement like so,

```
SET t=!test:~1,%number%!
```

If I understand this correctly, the `!` makes the interpreter read `test:~1, %number%` instead of before where it was reading `test:~1` and `number` separately due to the interpreter thinking the expression was closed because of using two `%` symbols. In another way, it thought you meant two expressions because of the paired `%` symbols. Thanks to Aacini for linking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990/9068733)  which helped me find the solution!

Comment: Yes. Same concept as one of your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410637/why-does-my-batch-file-echo-the-array-name-and-number-instead-of-the-string). `set operator=!operator[%operator%]!`

Comment: Thanks, am I mistaken in asking another question about a specific function of a different bit of code?

Comment: May I ask you to upvote the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)?